# Ubuntu 12.04 - can't detect 2 displays

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, display

I'm running ubuntu 12.04, my graphic card is:

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

I have 2 Display but the desktop is not extended, both displays show the same screen. If I go to display settings, it says that a laptop display is detected, but not 2 Displays.

How can I use both Displays for an extended view?

Comment: what is the output of `xrandr -q` command

Answer (score 1):

Same sort of problem occurred on my system(i5-4570s).
And I found this page..

But I have just solved this probrem, NOW!

Just Try It!

My vga is

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

/var/log/Xorg.0.log showed fbdev modules was loaded and
 Display was detected as Single Virtual Monitor.

There are some new intel driver modules packages,
 but old xserver packages on 12.04 is not suitable to install those.
Finally, I found newer xserver package distributor.

```
https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that, new intel driver module is loaded and 
 2 displays are also detected.