# Displays do not extend

Tags: 12.04, display

I have two monitors connected to my computer, one on the VGA and other on the HDMI output. But I am not able to extend these displays. Both monitors show the same thing. When I go to display settings, this is what is shown. What do I need to do in order to extend these displays?
[image: Display settings]

## UPDATE:

Well, I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423052/ubuntu-12-04-cant-detect-2-displays) and followed the exact steps. When I rebooted the system, it got stuck on "Stopping System V runlevel compatibility". After this I tried installing various display managers as explained in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1807612). Installing lightdm-gtk-greeter did help to display the login screen, but the screen went blank after I logged in. Finally I ended up upgrading ubuntu to 14.04 and everything seems to work. Luckily I had timeshift installed and took a snapshot before upgrading package distributor. Updating the question itself instead of posting it an answer as I could not find a way of extending monitors on 12.04.

Comment: Great that you got it working, was going to suggest an upgrade for you, as 12.04 support will be ending soon.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the displays can be recognized by your computer, you can do this by typing `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open a terminal and type:

```
xrandr
```

This should output some information about your displays. You can then setup your displays based on this. `man xrandr` in a terminal will help with this.

In my monitor setup:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --auto --orientation left --output DP-1 --auto --right-of DVI-I-1
```

Where the output DVI-I-1 is set to have left orientation, automatic resolution, and left of the output DP-1 which also has automatic resolution set.

Comment: The output of xrandr: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080       0.0* 
   1280x1024       0.0  
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0  
`

Comment: It does not show the 2nd monitor. But the displays are working and show same thing. Does this mean that my computer does not support multiple displays?

Comment: It may be that you do not have the proper drivers installed. What graphics module/card does your computer use?

Comment: the output of `lspci | grep VGA` shows this: `Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`